# How to wait for promise to get resolve and execute other lines of code after

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, fetch

I am new to js async/await. I am using $.each utility and I found that the lines of code is getting executed async manner even after using await so, I switched from $.each -> for, that works for me

Comment: return the promise ... i.e `return fetch(url, {` - however, using async/await as a callback to `$.each` has the same pitfalls as it does in using it `.forEach` ... the TLDR of that is ... don't do that, use regular for loops (all the way up the nested loops you have) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `await` nested in some `$.each(ticketIds, async function` loops, but realise that these `async` functions *return* when they encounter an `await`, returning a promise: the loop will thus produce a set of promises and continue without awaiting *those* promises.

One of the simplest solutions is to use `for` loops, so that all the `await` expressions run in the context of the outer `async` function.

So for instance, change this:

```
$.each(rowGroups, function(serviceName, obj) {
    // ...
});
```

to this:

```
for (let [serviceName, obj] of Object.entries(rowGroups)) {
    // ...
}
```

...and do this for all those nested loops.

There is, I think, one instance where the iteration is not over a *plain* object, but over an *array*, so then change from this:

```
$.each(issueLinks, function(index, issue) {
```

to this:

```
for (let [index, issue] of issueLinks.entries()) {
```

This solves your problem. But as noted in comments, you also have another issue: `createJiraResponse` will remain undefined, because your `client` function does not *return* the promise. So either remove the braces from that arrow function, or change `fetch(` to `return fetch(`.

Comment: of course, `const client` should **return** a promise too

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am trying this rn but when the `const client` return a promise. I need to make sure all the promises are resolved before executing the last line of code which is a POST request using `payload`

Comment: @hitendra, that is indeed the purpose of replacing all your `$.each` loops with `for` loops. Then the last line will only execute when all the awaited promises have resolved.

Comment: And then Jaromanda's comment is also true: `client` currently does not return anything, so you must fix that any how (added a paragraph about that to my answer).